# Chaining the Imperius curse

Tags: harry-potter

What would happen if a wizard `w` successfully casts the Imperius curse on a equally powerful wizard `a` and then order him to cast the same curse back on `w`?

Follow-up questions.

It is established that casting the curse can be done [recursively](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53457).

What would happen in the case of a chain of casts that would hit back the original wizard?
`w->a->b->c->w`

The original wizard could rather command the last wizard `c`, in the chain, to curse his first target instead.
`w->a->b->c->a` wich would create a loop of `a->b->c->a`...

In what kind of limbo would wizards `a`, `b` and `c` exist in?

( for the sake of simplicity, we can assume that every curse target is not very good at resisting the curse )

Comment: This seems primarily opinion-based (as there is no canon answer AFAIR) **and** is asking more than one question. You might want to edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the curse can be cast recursively, we know that the master *M* can control *A* who can control *B* and so forth, with the chain of control eventually back at the hands of *M*.

Since *A* is already under the control of *M*, and anyone under *A* will be placed under *M*, if *A* casts the curse on himself, it should have no noticeable effect.

Now if *A* (or someone else down the line) casts the curse back on *M* to form a loop: By following the above logic, again, nothing should happen. *M* will be placed under *A*'s control, who is already under *M*'s control, so again, it will effectively be as if nothing had happened.

I'm not sure how much strain the control puts on *M*; let's say he makes a loop and at some point loses focus, ie. breaks the curse. I've listed three possibilities in order of likelihood:

- The entire chain is broken, everyone (re)gains control of only themselves.
- The first node (*A*) gains control of the entire chain *and* *M*.
- The one who cast the spell on *M* gains control over the entire chain.

That's the logical answer inferred from the recursive properties of the curse. But I wouldn't be surprised to find a canon answer that states the control is reversed, but that's just a conjecture.

Comment: You assume M controls everyone else, that is ok and it then if works like you said. But what if a wizard only controls the target he actually casted the spell *on*. M tells A to cast the curse on B, but who did the actual casting M or A? Or in other words, does M controls B only because he also controls A, or is A irrelevant once the curse has been cast on B by A.

Comment: @self. I'm assuming a single-file line of curses, so if M controls A and B, it is implied that B is under A who is under M. If we allow different branches to converge, say M controls A and B _directly_, and then B or A try to control each-other, we venture in the territory of direct acyclic graphs, which is a bit more complex than I'm comfortable with in Scifi.SE. To answer your comment: In my examples A did the actual _casting_ on B, ie. said the words, under M's control.