# Does the Imperius Curse have a domino like effect?

Tags: harry-potter

If person A controls person B, and person B controls person C,D,E, and F and so on and so forth, then does person A control persons C,D,E, and F as well? In other words, all are under person A's control?

If so, can someone control person A and then control persons B,C,D,E, and F as a result of the control "chain?"

=[image]

Comment: This has been asked and closed before [here...](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58705/chaining-the-imperius-curse)

Comment: So **that's** how dominoes work...

Comment: @TheDarkLord - well, how would they possibly work if they couldn't mind control each other?