# How could Krum use the Cruciatus Curse in HPGoF?

Tags: harry-potter, unforgivable-curse

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Viktor Krum uses the Cruciatus Curse on Cedric in the maze under the Imperius Curse. But Bellatrix Lestrange says in the Order of the Phoenix:

> "You need to mean them, Potter! You need to really want to cause pain — to enjoy it — righteous anger won’t hurt me for long — I’ll show you how it is done, shall I?"

So does what Bellatrix said not apply when someone uses the Cruciatus Curse when under the Imperius? I'm assuming that's true, since I doubt Krum would have *really* meant it, but I'd just like to hear some other thoughts on this.

Comment: This seems very subjective. Per the [FAQ]: "*Avoid asking subjective questions where … there is no actual problem to be solved:* **“I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”**"

Comment: So youre basically asking how come a person capable of doing things under the imperius they usually cant or wont do? Then at least let's make it interesting and ask if a person imperius' d could cast imperius too.

Comment: @Morrigan - Asked and closed; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58705/chaining-the-imperius-curse

Comment: Seems a fair question about the parameters of the Imperius Curse to me.

Comment: Dumbledore should've let you teach, @TheDarkLord

Comment: @witchy They actually can. Don't remember who does it but it was under Death Eater's control if I’m not very much mistaken.

Answer (score 7):

## Krum was likely channeling Crouch Junior's emotions to cast the Curse.

It's correct to say that someone under the Imperius Curse wouldn't be able to muster up the necessary emotional strength or willpower to cast an Unforgiveable Curse. Being under the Imperius Curse is described as like being emptied of all emotion and internal thoughts.

> It was the most wonderful feeling. Harry felt a floating sensation as **every thought and worry in his head was wiped gently away**, leaving nothing but a vague, untraceable happiness. He stood there feeling immensely relaxed, only dimly aware of everyone watching him.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 15, Beauxbatons and Durmstrang)*.</sub>

Someone under the Imperius Curse is a blank slate. Krum wouldn't have been able to call on any emotions of his own to cast the Cruciatus Curse.

However, he could have channeled Crouch Junior's anger or hatred. The caster of the Imperius Curse is described as having total control over their subject. If the castee is a puppet then the caster is a puppetmaster. He or she can make their victim feel some of their own anger or hatred if they want to. This is part of the connection between the mind (and therefore thoughts/emotions) of the caster and the subject.

> Harry raised the hawthorn wand beneath the Cloak, pointed it at the old goblin and whispered, for the first time in his life, "*Imperio!*"
>   A curious sensation shot down Harry's arm, **a feeling of tingling warmth that seemed to flow from his mind,** down the sinews and veins connecting him to the wand and the curse it had just cast.
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26, Gringotts)*.</sub>

So Krum didn't have the energy or the emotions to cast the Curse. But Crouch Junior did and he used Krum as an empty prop to accomplish his purpose.

Answer (score 5):

## It may have been part of Krum’s “instructions” to use Crucio.

Victims of the Imperius Curse feel internally relaxed, and have no emotions of their own. However, the person who cast the Imperius Curse could probably command the victim to feel certain emotions if they needed them to. From what we see of Krum’s actions in the maze, Barty Crouch Jr. could have simply commanded him to cast Crucio on the other Triwizard champions (presumably except Harry). We see him using Crucio on Cedric, and Cedric said he heard Fleur scream, so it’s possible casting Crucio could be a direct command.

> “Did you hear Fleur scream earlier?’ said Harry.
>
> ‘Yeah,’ said Cedric. ‘You don’t think Krum got her, too?’
>
> ‘I don’t know,’ said Harry slowly.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 31 (The Third Task)*</sup></sub>

Under the Imperius Curse, it might not matter what Krum’s emotions are. If Barty Crouch Jr. was actively controlling Krum’s every action, it was probably Crouch’s emotions being used to cast the Cruciatus Curse, as the Dark Lord says.

## Also, people can do things under Imperio they normally can’t.

People placed under the Imperius Curse can be capable of things they wouldn’t be while not under it. “Moody” commands Neville to do gymnastics that were clearly beyond his usual capabilities.

> “Moody began to beckon students forwards in turn and put the Imperius Curse upon them. Harry watched as, one by one, his classmates did the most extraordinary things under its influence. Dean Thomas hopped three times around the room, singing the national anthem. Lavender Brown imitated a squirrel. Neville performed a series of quite astonishing gymnastics he would certainly not have been capable of in his normal state.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 15 (Beauxbatons and Durmstrang)*</sup></sub>

If Krum was commanded to cast the Cruciatus Curse, it might outweigh the fact that he doesn’t “mean it”. His Cruciatus under the Imperius Curse probably wouldn’t be as effective as one cast by someone like Bellatrix while she’s actively enjoying it, but it would probably be effective enough to disable or slow down the other champions.

Comment: **His Cruciatus under the Imperius Curse probably wouldn’t be as effective as one cast by someone like Bellatrix while she’s actively enjoying it** Spoken like a true expert! I can't imagine there being anyone who enjoys it more than you - that is Miss Bella! And as Dumbledore says she likes to play with her food before killing it. One of my first thoughts was also that victims of Imperio can do things they normally can't and I would argue that Crouch Jr. had all the emotion he needed; or perhaps he didn't want to torture them terribly so much as just disable them. That's also quite possible?

Comment: @Pryftan Haha of course! There’s no one who loves to use the Cruciatus Curse more than me! ;) That people are capable of things they normally wouldn’t be while under the Imperius Curse was the first thing I thought of too - someone commanded to use the Cruciatus Curse would likely be able to use it with some effect. It’s also true that Barty Crouch Jr. just needed to disable Cedric - if the Cruciatus Curse wasn’t fully effective, once it slowed him down that’s all he’d need.

Comment: @Miss Bella Agreed. Also he probably didn't expect to be discovered and what would happen if he caused more damage than is necessary? Well he did draw attention to himself in the end and he also in the height of the plot forgot to take Polyjuice Potion (not that I feel it even matters; I want to say actually he was still in the form of Mad-Eye when Dumbledore &c blasted through the door stunning him).